# Can I disable Android/TouchWiz zooming my app's contents when system zoom is on?

Tags: android, cordova, samsung-touchwiz

TouchWiz has a setting called **Screen Zoom** with 3 levels - **Small**, **Medium** and **Large** - which changes the text (and possibly other?) sizes across Android. OxygenOS from OnePlus has a **Display Size** setting that can be used to achieve the same effect.

Is there a way in which I can make it such that the text size in my Android app remains the same irrespective of that system setting?

If it matters, I want it to be done for a Cordova app in Android.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's a very useful setting for people with vision problems, and they might not be able to use your app with the standard setting.

Comment: It's an enterprise app, and that zoom causes text issues, and business is not ready to spend the time to "support" it.